# Reload certificates server at runtime

Tags: scala, runtime, keystore, akka-http, truststore

Is it possible to reload at runtime certificates in a web server using API of Akka-HTTP? I would that the HttpsConnectionContext is reloaded without shutdown of server. Is there a way to do that? I've already implemented a mechanism that read the renew of certificate but my problem is to reload the context at runtime.
Below I show how my server is started:

```
  log.info("HTTPS ENABLED!")
  val https: HttpsConnectionContext = newHttpsConnectionContext()

  val (host, port, connectionContext) = ("0.0.0.0", 8080, https)
  log.debug(s" Binding RESTful Web Services ...  https://$host:$port/")
  val bindingFuture =
    Http().bindAndHandle(
      endpoints,
      host,
      port,
      connectionContext
    )

  bindingFuture.onComplete {
    case Success(bind) =>
      log.info(s"HTTPS server binding $bind")
      binding = Some(bind)
      log.warn(
        s" Service online at https://$host:$port/"
      )

    case Failure(ex) =>
      log.error(
        s" Failed to bind to https://$host:$port/ - Error : ${ex.getMessage}"
      )
      close()
  }
}

def newHttpsConnectionContext(): HttpsConnectionContext = {
import myService.TlsSettings
log.debug(
  s"Creating a new HTTPS Connection Context between my Service (Server) and Clients..."
)
val sslParameters: Option[SSLParameters] = None
val sslConnectionContext: HttpsConnectionContext =
  ConnectionContext.https(
    TlsSettings(
      ApplicationProperties.clientCert,
      ApplicationProperties.clientPrivKey
    ).sslContext,
    None,
    Some(SSL_CIPHER_SUITES),
    Some(SSL_PROTOCOLS),
    Some(TLSClientAuth.Need),
    sslParameters
  )
log.info(
  s"HTTPS Connection Context my Service <--> Clients created! $sslConnectionContext"
)
sslConnectionContext
```

}

Comment: are you handling ssl in akka-http for incoming (server) or outgoing (client) connections? can you please add a very simplifier version of how you bootstrap akka-http and ssl handling?

Comment: Hi, I've edited my post. I'm handling for incoming connections (I'm a server)

Comment: I would re-think about why would you like to do that. You should choose a CA, create yourself a certificate, and go with it all along. Your client should also know how he needs to encrypt the data being sent to you. If you change it on the fly, you'll probably use existing clients. Can you please elaborate what is the scenario you are trying to resolve?

Comment: Yes, there are existing clients, not handled by me, that open secure connections to my service (mutual authentication). My server is started with an HttpsConnectionContext but the certificate that it must send to the clients is renewed at runtime (once an hour). So I need to reload HttpsConnectionContext but without the shoutdown of server so as not to create a disservice.

Comment: Hi Riccardo do you have any updates regarding your issue? I think I have an answer which may work